# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dot_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (924,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to deep learning, was trying to build a mf model, when i ran this code, got this error message:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dot_1 to have shape
>   (1,) but got array with shape (924,)

```
def build_model(intUserSize, intMovieSize, intLatentSize, boolBias=False):

    print("usersize",intUserSize,"movieSize",intMovieSize)

    UserInput = Input(shape=(1,), name="UserInput")
    UserEmbedding = Embedding(intUserSize, intLatentSize, embeddings_initializer='random_normal', embeddings_regularizer=l2(0.01),name='UserEmbedding')(UserInput)
    UserEmbedding = Flatten()(UserEmbedding)
    UserEmbedding = Dropout(0.3)(UserEmbedding)

    MInput = Input(shape=(1,), name="midInput")
    MEmbedding = Embedding(intMovieSize, intLatentSize, embeddings_initializer='random_normal', embeddings_regularizer=l2(0.01),
                               name='membedding')(MInput)
    MEmbedding = Flatten()(MEmbedding)
    MEmbedding = Dropout(0.3)(MEmbedding)

    RatingHat = Dot(axes=1)([UserEmbedding, MEmbedding])

    model = Model([UserInput, MInput], RatingHat)

    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse", metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model

    model.fit([trainu,trainm],trainrate,epochs=10,batch_size=100,verbose=2)
```

Please help!

Comment: Your problem is here I think: `Dot(axes=1)([UserEmbedding, MEmbedding])`. Check the sizes of `UserEmbedding` and MEmbedding`.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what happend in Embedding layer, its out put size is depend on input？

Comment: Take a look at [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding)